# How to properly smooth the hue of an image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Suppose you have an image in some kind of color space with a hue-like channel, i.e. a channel that is inherently circular.
For instance, in typical HSL or HSV channels, a hue of 0 or a hue of 256 both correspond to the exact same color, usually pure red, while 255 is ever so slightly more bluish, but still almost pure red.
Now if you, say, apply a Gaussian blur on such a channel, along a line where 0 and 255 touch, you'll "smooth it out" the long way round, forming a gradient between the two reds going across the entire rainbow. - This result will almost certainly not be desired.

A second problem happens due to a singularity at a Lightness/Value and/or Saturation of 0, in which case the Hue could technically take on an arbitrary value. - Most color space conversions simply pick a hue of 0 when converting color spaces, since for almost all usual use-cases it wouldn't matter. But if I were to blur, it absolutely does.

How would a typical Gaussian Blur algorithm have to be altered to properly deal with at least the (more important) first problem, ideally also the second?

I assume the second one is much tougher and could not be done with just the Hue channel alone but would rather need information from the other two to special case for the singularity, but hopefully there is some reasonably simple tweak that fixes the first.

If a specific algorithm is necessary for the answer, a nice simple and fast method would be the approximation using repeated box convolutions, as has been used, for instance, [here](http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html)

For convenience, here is a copy + paste from that site, doing three horizontal and three vertical box convolutions:

```js
function gaussBlur_4 (scl, tcl, w, h, r) {
    var bxs = boxesForGauss(r, 3);
    boxBlur_4 (scl, tcl, w, h, (bxs[0]-1)/2);
    boxBlur_4 (tcl, scl, w, h, (bxs[1]-1)/2);
    boxBlur_4 (scl, tcl, w, h, (bxs[2]-1)/2);
}
function boxBlur_4 (scl, tcl, w, h, r) {
    for(var i=0; i<scl.length; i++) tcl[i] = scl[i];
    boxBlurH_4(tcl, scl, w, h, r);
    boxBlurT_4(scl, tcl, w, h, r);
}
function boxBlurH_4 (scl, tcl, w, h, r) {
    var iarr = 1 / (r+r+1);
    for(var i=0; i<h; i++) {
        var ti = i*w, li = ti, ri = ti+r;
        var fv = scl[ti], lv = scl[ti+w-1], val = (r+1)*fv;
        for(var j=0; j<r; j++) val += scl[ti+j];
        for(var j=0  ; j<=r ; j++) { val += scl[ri++] - fv       ;   tcl[ti++] = Math.round(val*iarr); }
        for(var j=r+1; j<w-r; j++) { val += scl[ri++] - scl[li++];   tcl[ti++] = Math.round(val*iarr); }
        for(var j=w-r; j<w  ; j++) { val += lv        - scl[li++];   tcl[ti++] = Math.round(val*iarr); }
    }
}
function boxBlurT_4 (scl, tcl, w, h, r) {
    var iarr = 1 / (r+r+1);
    for(var i=0; i<w; i++) {
        var ti = i, li = ti, ri = ti+r*w;
        var fv = scl[ti], lv = scl[ti+w*(h-1)], val = (r+1)*fv;
        for(var j=0; j<r; j++) val += scl[ti+j*w];
        for(var j=0  ; j<=r ; j++) { val += scl[ri] - fv     ;  tcl[ti] = Math.round(val*iarr);  ri+=w; ti+=w; }
        for(var j=r+1; j<h-r; j++) { val += scl[ri] - scl[li];  tcl[ti] = Math.round(val*iarr);  li+=w; ri+=w; ti+=w; }
        for(var j=h-r; j<h  ; j++) { val += lv      - scl[li];  tcl[ti] = Math.round(val*iarr);  li+=w; ti+=w; }
    }
}

function boxesForGauss(sigma, n)  // standard deviation, number of boxes
{
    var wIdeal = Math.sqrt((12*sigma*sigma/n)+1);  // Ideal averaging filter width 
    var wl = Math.floor(wIdeal);  if(wl%2==0) wl--;
    var wu = wl+2;

    var mIdeal = (12*sigma*sigma - n*wl*wl - 4*n*wl - 3*n)/(-4*wl - 4);
    var m = Math.round(mIdeal);
    // var sigmaActual = Math.sqrt( (m*wl*wl + (n-m)*wu*wu - n)/12 );

    var sizes = [];  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) sizes.push(i<m?wl:wu);
    return sizes;
}
```

But I'm mainly interested in the actual algorithmic changes that are necessary, not necessarily in a specific implementation in a specific language.

Comment: i dont think anyone will understand your second paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay in the Hue color space, and use circular data statistics, see [here](http://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Circular_Data_Analysis.pdf) or [here](http://webspace.ship.edu/pgmarr/Geo441/Lectures/Lec%2016%20-%20Directional%20Statistics.pdf).

A gaussian filter is just a convolution filter, so basically a weighted average. So in such color space, you simply use a weighted circular average: it is computed by decomposing each value/angle into sin/cos, then average the sin/cos, and go back to the angle/value.